# What is an approach for designing complex FSMs?

Tags: complexity-theory, fsm

At work, we use FSMs. Recently, I had to design an FSM for a problem that I deem "a little too complex for a simple FSM". Why? Because the problem has about 6 different data dimensions, and many permutations of this data impact the behaviour of the solution significantly. My brain thinks "6 data attributes means 2^6 +1 permutations of this data" if it were all boolean data. Furthermore, there are about 8 inputs that can happen at any given time.

This problem made me aware that my FSM creating skills stop at simple problems used in my hobby projects. At work, we are constrained to use FSMs. That means, I cannot just say "this problem is outside of the scope of FSMs. I'll use something else." Indeed, the FSM platform we have in place does provide a lot of power for our solutions.

Question: What is an approach for designing an FSM when the problem is sufficiently complex? I've researched a bit on this and found a few papers which, honestly, didn't help me much. I hope there are some best practices for this, and all I'm asking for is one. Please and thanks.

Comment: I suppose you mean [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), not one of the many other FSMs, such as [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster).  Or [Fecal Sludge Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septage)....

Comment: Anyway, the question is far too broad for SO.  It would probably be better suited for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but if you decide to pose it there then please do delete it here.

Comment: If FSM means "finite state machine" then my answer would be general: FSM is simply a programming language like any other. How do you design FSMs for complex tasks? How do you eat an elephant?

Comment: Have you considered writing a generator for FSMs from a higher level language? If the overall function you have to compute is computable by an FSM, you can probably work with a simple scripting language and then use a translator to generate the FSM from the scripting language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you might be experiencing the usual "state-transition explosion", which is the known problem of traditional "flat" FSMs. The traditional FSMs "explode", because they inflict repetitions of the same reactions in many states. FSMs lack any mechanisms to capture commonalities of behavior among states. The long know solution is to use [Hierarchical State Machines](http://www.state-machine.com/doc/concepts.html#HSM) (a.k.a. Harel statecharts or [UML state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)). HSM support the concept of **state nesting**, in which sub-states inherit behavior from the surrounding superstate(s). When used correctly, state nesting eliminates the repetitions and counteracts the "explosion" problem. Most non-trivial problems are not really tractable with FSMs, but are quite manageable with HSMs.